# Can I safely disconnect when the final scoreboard is shown?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

When playing competitive mode in CS GO, at the end of a round the scoreboard is shown and it takes sometimes up to 30 seconds for the match to actually finish and go back to the menu.

**Can I safely disconnect during this event or will I suffer a match making penalty?**

Comment: Consider accepting my answer since I tried this over the course of a week and it is not only speculation like the other answer.

Comment: @Assylum it looks like that user has been deleted, I don't know how stack exchange will go about switching answers...

Answer (score 10):

I tried this in at least 20 matches and disconnected immediately after the scoreboard showed up and the prizes where drawn. I never got banned.

**So yes, it is safe to disconnect when the scoreboard is shown.**

Comment: Correct answer. You also receive the Steam message "1 new item" exactly at the end of the game, where the item drops are shown. When disconnecting, it will ask you if you really want to because... penalty! But you won't get any penalty after the game ended.

Answer (score 1):

It's safe to disconnect after the scoreboard and dropping items. (But after these I recommend you to wait for a couple seconds.)

Answer (score -2):

It's definitaly not safe to leave when the final scoreboard is shown! I've been banned for 7 days once becuase I was disconnected from the lobby but then I could reconnect and abandon, and I reconnected, but I was alone. So I tried leaving again but then abandon. Guess what happened. BANNED FOR 7 DAYS!

Comment: ummm there isnt enough credible info in this answer...